# Error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, crash

I've got an error while compiling (Release/Debug)

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM cordovaSettingForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003ea6ae0'
```

After build successfully myProject. I was open my project in Xcode and click the run button on Xcode. the project build successfully and display the lunch screen in simulator device. After that stuff I get an error in main.m, and this is what I see in console:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");                              Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

        return retVal;
    }
}

2019-09-27 15:19:14.943154+0530 myApp[3086:93649] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///Users/mk/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EC5630C3-373A-45AD-A404-5628B1B329B9/data/Containers/Data/Application/06D2441B-F5B5-47B8-B6A7-68AEA36BB0D6/Library/Cookies/com.test.my-app.binarycookies
2019-09-27 15:19:14.954425+0530 myApp[3086:93649] Apache Cordova native platform version 5.0.1 is starting.
2019-09-27 15:19:14.954596+0530 myApp[3086:93649] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2019-09-27 15:19:14.972439+0530 myApp[3086:93649] -[__NSDictionaryM cordovaSettingForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000011cc900
2019-09-27 15:19:14.981981+0530 myApp[3086:93649] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM cordovaSettingForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000011cc900'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b98bde __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff503b5b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bb9704 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b9d7bc ___forwarding___ + 1436
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b9f6c8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   myApp                               0x000000010a028723 -[CDVViewController viewDidLoad] + 227
    6   myApp                               0x000000010a004433 -[MainViewController viewDidLoad] + 51
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46af87c2 -[UIViewController _sendViewDidLoadWithAppearanceProxyObjectTaggingEnabled] + 83
    8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46afd6d3 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1084
    9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46afdaf0 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47199b55 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 150
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4719920b -[UIWindow _updateLayerOrderingAndSetLayerHidden:actionBlock:] + 232
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4719a2c9 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 362
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff471ad46d -[UIWindow _mainQueue_makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    14  myApp                               0x000000010a01ef3f -[CDVAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 703
    15  myApp                               0x000000010a0041ab -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 187
    16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4715994f -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 232
    17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4715b2e7 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 3980
    18  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47160c05 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1281
    19  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff468b58b1 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 122
    20  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46d96cd5 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 83
    21  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff468b63c3 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 198
    22  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff468b5e84 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 474
    23  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff468b61f3 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 821
    24  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff468b5a85 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 345
    25  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff468b9e70 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke_2 + 159
    26  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46cbdf8b +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 865
    27  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46db51cf _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 240
    28  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff468b9b9e __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 153
    29  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46db50d2 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 84
    30  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff468b9a0c -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 381
    31  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46717c96 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 657
    32  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4671681b -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 248
    33  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff467179c0 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 210
    34  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4715f262 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 535
    35  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46cdf774 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 361
    36  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff362e1d43 -[FBSSceneImpl _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 442
    37  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff3630a00c __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.154 + 102
    38  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff362ecd21 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 220
    39  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36309c9d __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 355
    40  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a387d64 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    41  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a38acd5 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 300
    42  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff3633108a __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
    43  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36330d78 -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 441
    44  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36331287 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 22
    45  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23afbac1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    46  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23afb9ec __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76
    47  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23afb1c4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
    48  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23af5ecf __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    49  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23af56b6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
    50  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff3815cbb0 GSEventRunModal + 65
    51  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47162a67 UIApplicationMain + 1621
    52  myApp                               0x000000010a0040d1 main + 65
    53  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff5123bcf5 start + 1
    54  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've implemented -[ application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist .

Are you using notificayion in your app ,if so make what they are asking else check your app if there is a method that have un ended loop so that it is causing the app to throw execption of rebound.

Comment: Hi @Mostafa thank you for responds.
Now I remove the "remote-notification". I don't needed any notification.
But It still got an error

Comment: Now remove the error for "remote-notification" from console.
And add a new error showing in console
2019-09-27 15:19:14.943154+0530 myApp[3086:93649] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///Users/mk/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EC5630C3-373A-45AD-A404-5628B1B329B9/data/Containers/Data/Application/06D2441B-F5B5-47B8-B6A7-68AEA36BB0D6/Library/Cookies/com.test.my-app.binarycookies

Comment: I think your application have storing files in app storage right?if so,you have made storing files wrong on ios but good on android so check your code so it works on both android and iphone . If your app is not about storing then tell me what is your app about.

Comment: I am using storage only for storing login information and nothing else. After login the app stores user informations like user id, name, login date time etc. I am using this code: 
`import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';`

Comment: Rarely this error occurs, and is due to problem in app permission  and in your place is storage error permission for ios.

Comment: Did you try to remove the build and rebuild it since i think its only matter of conflict after the first wrong build

Comment: If you have checked all what i said and everything is made, then remove the storage plugin and then add you data to sqlite database, plus its more secure anyway for storing login data.since storage is webview made while sqlite database is native so use it plus don't forget to remove the storage plugin and make the required procedure.